# How to download CS:GO demo from match sharing code

Tags: rest

Since [9/17/2019](https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2019/09/25513/), Valve provided an API that allows players to give access to third-party websites to download their matchs history.

From [this documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Access_Match_History), I have been able to get all my sharing code `CSGO-xxxxx-xxxxx...`, ready to download the matchs ! But, I didn't find any information about how to download them.
In [this page](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithGameIssue/?appid=730&issueid=128) and the last one, we can read `Third-party websites and applications can use this authentication code to access your match history, your overall performance in those matches, download replays of your matches, and analyze your gameplay.` and `This page outlines the basics of creating a website or application to access players match history and help with players statistics tracking and gameplay analysis.`. So, I'm pretty sure their might be a way.

Most of all, a famous website, https://csgostats.gg is [able to download demos from this sharing code](https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/1629665087665778963/), so...

I know that this code `CSGO-xxxxx-xxxxx...` code be use like this `steam://rungame/730/:steamID:/+csgo_download_match%20CSGO-xxxxx-xxxxx` to watch the demo. But my goal is really to download it, to be able to parse it. So, I'm not looking for [this way](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255755/how-to-use-the-csgo-sharing-code).

So, I'm looking for a way to download a CSGO demo using Valve's access token : [image]

You can download CSGO demo with this link : `http://replay131.valve.net/730/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx.dem.bz2`, but I havn't find a way to convert the sharing code to the demo's name.

I'm not sure if this question should be here or in software engineering ? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I forgot to answer my own question.

Since 4 months, I used this answer : https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/glwlq1/how_to_download_csgo_demo_from_match_sharing_code/fr0f8q5/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

But, once I got my `MatchID, OutcomeID and TokenID`, I use [boiler-writter](https://github.com/akiver/boiler-writter) to download the .info. Then inside, I can easily find the link of the demo.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a way to parse the demo into json data?

Answer (score 0):

CSGO-Demos-Manager (https://github.com/akiver/CSGO-Demos-Manager) can do this. It is written in C#. Unfortunately I have been unable to find any other solution.